# assign values to catch parameter

Tags: java

In the docs for `multiple try-catch` there is a statement.

`If a catch block handles more than one exception type, then the catch parameter is implicitly final. In this example, the catch parameter ex is final and therefore you cannot assign any values to it within the catch block`

But I don't get it. What do they mean by `cannot assign any values`? I can all every method of `exception` object as far as I remember. What `assignment` they are talking about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a [multi-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) then you cannot change the `Exception` reference;

```
try {
} catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
  ex = null; // <-- NOT LEGAL, the ex is final.
}
```

Comment: LoL. It was so obvious. I failed really hard.

Answer (score 2):

It means you cannot re-assign object `e` to something else because a final object can be assigned only once.

```
try {
} catch(SomeException | SomeDifferentException e) {
  e = new FooException(); //Invalid
  or
  e = someOtherExcpetionObject; //Invalid
}
```